# TypeError: __init__() takes from 1 to 3 positional arguments but 4 were given

Tags: python

I have hit a problem with one of the examples in the book [Beginning Python Games Development Second Edition](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1484209710).

It has me setting up a vector class (full code at the end of the Q) with the following `__init__` function:

```
def __init__(self, x=0, y=0):
    self.x = x
    self.y = y
```

It then asks me to run this code snippet against it:

```
from Vector2 import *

A = (10.0, 20,0)
B = (30.0, 35.0)
AB = Vector2.from_points(A, B)
step = AB * .1
position = Vector2(A, B)
step = AB * .1
print(*A)
position = Vector2(*A)
for n in range(10):
    position += step
    print(position)
```

The result is the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/Charles Jr/Dropbox/Python/5-14 calculating positions.py", line 10, in <module>
    position = Vector2(*A)
TypeError: __init__() takes from 1 to 3 positional arguments but 4 were given
```

When I put a print on the *A, it comes up as just 2 numbers, as you would expect. Why is it somehow turning this into 4?

Full Vector2 code:

```
import math

class Vector2:

    def __init__(self, x=0, y=0):
        self.x = x
        self.y = y

    def __str__(self):
        return "(%s, %s)"%(self.x, self.y)

    def from_points(P1, P2):
        print("foo")
        return Vector2( P2[0] - P1[0], P2[1] - P1[1])

    def get_magnitude(self):
        return math.sqrt( self.x**2 + self.y**2 )

    def normalise(self):
        magnitude = self.get_magnitude()
        self.x /= magnitude
        self.y /= magnitude

    # rhs stands for right hand side
    def __add__(self, rhs):
        return Vector2(self.x + rhs.x, self.y + rhs.y)

    def __sub__(self, rhs):
        return Vector2(self.x - rhs.x, self.y - rhs.y)

    def __neg__(self):
        return Vector2(-self.x, -self.y)

    def __mul__(self, scalar):
        return Vector2(self.x * scalar, self.y * scalar)

    def __truediv__(self, scalar):
        return Vector2(self.x / scalar, self.y / scalar)
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`A` contains *three* elements, `(10.0, 20, 0)`, because you used a comma, not a `.` decimal point when defining it:

```
A = (10.0, 20,0)
#            ^ that's a comma
```

Together with the `self` argument that means you passed in 4 arguments to the `__init__` method.

Comment: Thank you. That was a really hard one to spot!

Answer (score 0):

```
A = (10.0, 20,0)
```

you should use

```
A = (10.0, 20.0)
```

so when you do instanciate

```
Vector(*A)
```

you dont pass 4 arguments (self, 10.0, 20, 0) but 3 arguments (self, 10.0, 20.0)

Answer (score 0):

**Note:** Sometimes adding a `self` as an argument to `__init__()` can cause a similar error,
so make sure to check you haven't passed self by mistake.

**This is wrong**

```
super().__init__(self,x,y)
```

**This is right**

```
super().__init__(x,y)
```